# Selenium WebDriverWait but still "Element is not clickable at point"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code (br is the webdriver and everything is imported fine).

The first 3 lines work fine but the link1.click() still gives me an error:

```
link = WebDriverWait(br, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "buttonNew Project")))
link.click()    
link1 = WebDriverWait(br, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "MP")))
link1.click()
```

And even though it should have waited until its clickable, I still get the the error:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (543, 170). Other element would receive the click: <div id="screenBlocker" style="width: 1920px; height: 979px; display: block; background-position: 940px 420px;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)(543, 170)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Other element would receive the click: `<div id="screenBlocker" st...`

`screenBlocker` does sound like a, well, Screen Blocker. You have a popup/overlay on top of the page which you need to close, make invisible.

If there is no visible "close" button, just make it invisible this way:

```
blocker = driver.find_element_by_id("screenBlocker")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style = {display: 'none'};", blocker)
```

Comment: that works! but its weird because if I run the first 3 lines, then run the 4th line a second later, its fine, so the screenBlocker seems to close slower than the element is clickable?

Comment: @user295944 yeah, probably a timing issue, I guess. Glad it worked.

Comment: That worked for a few things but I ended up looking at this: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2766