# Waiting for an Element to Be Clickable using Selenium WebDriverWait Does Not Work

Tags: java, selenium

There's a menu item that I want to click.

However just before this click, in my test flow I have a modal open, which prevents clicking on the menu item. Also, when closed, the modal will fade instead of disappearing instantly.

What I do is close the menu item and then place a wait for the menu item to be clickable, before performing the click:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), time);
    wait.withMessage(message);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logging.logException(e);
    }

    clickOn(locator);
```

However this does not work, as I'm running each time into the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (158, 565). Other element would receive the click: <div class="globalpopup with-data slideout">...</div>
```

I also have Selenium set-up to take a screenshot each time an exception occurs and in the screenshot I can clearly see that the modal is in the process of fading out.
So the close button for it has been clicked, but at this point I'm thinking the wait should come into effect and pause execution until the modal fully disappears and the menu item can be clicked. Which does not happen.

Now I usually fix this by adding a bit of sleep time, as it's quite predictable how long it takes the modal to fade out. However I'd really like to figure out a more elegant solution, which can apply in all situations.

My understanding is that elementToBeClickable does not account for when the element is covered by another element, which I find quite silly. Is there a way to simulate such a wait (notCoveredByOtherElement), as it's exactly what I'd need?

P.S. I'm using Selenium 2.53. Have not tried v3 yet, although I'd happily make the effort to start switching to it if someone can confirm that this case is handled properly in this new version.

Comment: Try instead with a wait condition on the invisibility of the modal popup.

Comment: Could you share `clickOn()` method as well..:)

Comment: can you post the link of the page you are trying to work on and your full code ? also, have you tried googling "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point" ? Here is the first search result. http://learn-automation.com/how-to-solve-element-is-not-clickable-at-pointxy-in-selenium/

Comment: @Grasshopper - thanks, this actually seems like the best solution here. I've tested it and it works, although for some reason it waits a bit longer than it should  (6-7 seconds).

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Nothing special about the method, just some logging we're doing and the click:
`getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();`

Comment: @testerjoe2 I've tried googling of course. The solution you highlight does not apply here, as the problem is that the element is not clickable, not that Chrome is not correctly finding it. I run into the exact same issue when using the Firefox driver as well.

Comment: @Mynsc Does it wait 6-7 sec after the modal popup goes away on screen?

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes, after the modal has disappeared. 

For clarity, I'm using
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator))`
on the close button of the modal.

Comment: @Mynsc - ok. Can you please share the link which you are trying to automate ?

Comment: possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36269619/10245

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this issue number of time and tried some solution which always worked for me.

1-Updated chrome driver to latest one 2.23

2-Get the coordinate then click on the link or button

3-Try to click using Y coordinates

```
// Find an element
 WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath"));

// Scroll the browser to the element's Y position
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")");

// Click the element

elementToClick.click();

// Find an element

WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath"));


// Scroll the browser to the element's Y position

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")");

 // Click the element
 elementToClick.click();
```

I have documented all in below link kindly check

[Solutions for Element is not clickable in Selenium](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-solve-element-is-not-clickable-at-pointxy-in-selenium/)

Comment: this doesn't seem to address the specific problem of an unfinished fade-out